# How to use adb shell to display a local image

Tags: android, adb

I want to use `adb shell` to tell my device to display an image on its SD card.  I thought this command would work:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity -d file:///storage/sdcard0/Android/data/<mypackage>/files/myfile.jpg
```

Unfortunately I get this error:

> Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN
>   cmp=com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity }
>   Error type 3
>   Error: Activity class
>   {com.android.browser/com.android.browser.BrowserActivity} does not
>   exist.

I also tried doing a `VIEW` action, and trying with only the `-n` or the `-d` parameters.

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d file:///storage/sdcard0/Android/data/<mypackage>/files/myfile.jpg
```

Using only the `-d` parameter results in this error (I tried both with and without the "file://" prefix on the path):

> Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW
>   dat=/storage/sdcard0/Android/data//files/myfile.jpg
>   }
>   Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent {
>   act=android.intent.action.VIEW
>   dat=/storage/sdcard0/Android/data//files/myfile.jpg
>   flg=0x10000000 }

The permissions on the file are:

```
-rw-rw-r-- root     sdcard_rw   198106 2013-01-02 21:29 gUD9w5.jpg
```

I'm testing with a rooted Galaxy Nexus running 4.1.1.

**Update**: I tried dtmilano's suggestion but the Crop tool gives a "Couldn't load the image" popup.  The stack trace from logcat is:

```
ActivityManager: START {dat=file:///storage/sdcard0/Android/data/<mypackage>/Pictures/myfile.jpg typ=image/* 
    flg=0x13000000 cmp=com.google.android.gallery3d/com.android.gallery3d.app.CropImage u=0} from pid 301
UriImage: fail to open: file:///storage/sdcard0/Android/data/<mypackage>/Pictures/myfile.jpg
UriImage: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard0/Android/data/<mypackage>/Pictures/myfile.jpg: 
    open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
UriImage:   at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
UriImage:   at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
UriImage:   at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:105)
UriImage:   at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:445)
UriImage:   at com.android.gallery3d.data.UriImage.openOrDownloadInner(UriImage.java:98)
UriImage:   at com.android.gallery3d.data.UriImage.openFileOrDownloadTempFile(UriImage.java:78)
UriImage:   at com.android.gallery3d.data.UriImage.prepareInputFile(UriImage.java:164)
UriImage:   at com.android.gallery3d.data.UriImage.access$100(UriImage.java:40)
UriImage:   at com.android.gallery3d.data.UriImage$RegionDecoderJob.run(UriImage.java:170)
UriImage:   at com.android.gallery3d.data.UriImage$RegionDecoderJob.run(UriImage.java:168)
UriImage:   at com.android.gallery3d.app.CropImage$LoadDataTask.run(CropImage.java:921)
UriImage:   at com.android.gallery3d.app.CropImage$LoadDataTask.run(CropImage.java:913)
UriImage:   at com.android.gallery3d.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:124)
UriImage:   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
UriImage:   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
UriImage:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
UriImage:   at com.android.gallery3d.util.PriorityThreadFactory$1.run(PriorityThreadFactory.java:43)
UriImage: Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
UriImage:   at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
UriImage:   at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
UriImage:   at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:400)
UriImage:   ... 16 more
```

I'm wondering if this is an internal SD card, and maybe the images are being treated as application data, so other apps can't access it?

Comment: It should work with `VIEW` and leaving off the `-n com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity`.  The system should then resolve the intent to the correct class.

Comment: That didn't seem to work for me, I've updated the question with the error I see.

Comment: Install a file manager app and try to browse and view it with that - should answer the permission question.  Maybe the file is accessible, but but not by that path name *to app userid's*.

Comment: What worked for me - Kitkat 4.4.4 - was `adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/foo.jpg -t image/jpeg`. The answer by dtmilano opens it in Documents for some reason.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should work, however it's dependant on the apps you have installed:

```
$ adb shell am start -t image/* -d file:///mnt/sdcard/myfile.jpg
```

Interestingly, it doesn't work if you select **Gallery** in **Complete action using...**, but works if you select **Crop picture**.
Also works with **Astro Image Viewer**.

Comment: I can get as far as seeing the "Complete action using..." popup, but it always says "Couldn't load the image".  Perhaps the issue is my path format (I've tried lots), or if this is an internal SD card, then maybe permissions are stopping other apps accessing the file.

Comment: Start by adding an image file to the root directory of the sdcard and verify that works. Then go for the other location.

Comment: Launching a file at the root directory works, so I am guessing this is a permissions issue.

Comment: Note that Gallery works if you explicitly add the VIEW action as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24280837/671393

Answer (score 3):

The quickest workaround I have for my requirement is to just pull the file off the device and test it on my local machine:

```
adb pull /storage/sdcard0/Android/data/<mypackage>/files/myfile.jpg ~/Downloads
```