# How to display a local image via adb shell

Tags: java, android, adb

I am trying to display a local image on my Samsung Note 3 via adb shell.
    `$adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -n com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity -d file:///storage/emulated/legacy/Pictures/red.png  $ 

this code works for my another display device, but not works for my Note 3, i get this error

Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.android.browser/com.android.browser.BrowserActivity} does not exist.
i tried also this code

$adb shell am start -t image/* -d file:///storage/emulated/legacy/Pictures/red.png $`
but still doesnt work.
Can anybody help me, really appreciate for that!

Answer (score 4):

Solved myself:

> adb shell am start -d
>   file:///storage/emulated/legacy/Pictures/tiger.jpg -t image/jpg -a
>   android.intent.action.VIEW