# Display image full screen through Android adb

Tags: java, android, shell, adb

I would like a way to display an image in full screen mode (without the home and status bar showing, images are same resolution as the device) on an Android device through ADB. The image could be either on the device itself of on the computer I am using to adb to the device, if that makes  a difference (my first thought was that the image would be on the computer, but I've found some answers that leverage the device's storage and that would be fine).

What I would eventually like to do is set up a script that displays an image in full screen and iterates to the next file on a keypress.

[This answer might be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257866/how-to-display-a-local-image-via-adb-shell), showing how to display an image, but it doesn't show the image in full screen mode.

Possible ideas I have had, but don't exactly know how to implement:

- Create an app that displays an image full screen and launch it with the required image as a parameter (not sure how to link the picture and the app from adb though).
- Use the -n parameter seen in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146223/how-to-use-adb-shell-to-display-a-local-image) and specify an app that only displays images in full screen (could maybe make this app, but a pre-made solution would be easiest).

Any help/advice/guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What that command is doing is starting an Activity that claims it can VIEW jpgs and launching it (passing it the file name via intent).  It is not a built in android functionality, its launching an app.  For you to display fullscreen as you wish, you need an app that does that, either by default or when some optional parameter is passed.  There is no app like that you can 100% count on being installed.  SO if you really need it, you'll need to write an app that does it.  It should be a pretty trivial app at least-  1 image view and a fullscreen style is all you need.

Comment: Thanks for the very quick response!

How can I specify my app as the one to be launched? If you can explain this, I will accept your answer. Also, I assume I would need to give an intent listener to that app, but unfortunately I have no experience working with intents (or listeners besides something like onClick) so I'm unfamiliar with how they work. If you could, would you mind giving me some generic code for how that would work?

Comment: If you launch the intent by name, you wouldn't need the listener.  And that's probably the easiest way to do it.

Comment: I agree that would be easiest, but then how do I get the image (url)?